# Android Gradle Build Slow

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to figure out why our Gradle build is so slow. Currently each time you hit build with no changes the build time is around 45 seconds. This is a single module project. I have turned on profiling and most of the time is spent on `:app:dexDebug`. We are build using Gradle 2.8 and my dex options are as follows:

```
dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

From the profile report:

```
:app 43.957s (total) 
:app:dexDebug 28.727s
```

Is there a way to speed this up? Why does dex have to be rebuilt each time?

Comment: Just as an FYI. The same project builds in ANT in under 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This might shed some light:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

[Gradle build slow on transformClassesWithDexForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158995/gradle-build-slow-on-transformclasseswithdexfordebug)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187443&q=attachments%3D0&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Try disabling data binding:

```
  dataBinding {
         enabled = true
  }
```

Also try

```
 ./gradlew  assembleDebug --profile
```