# Android Studio instant build slow full build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-run

When `Instant Run` is enabled, the full build will take up my 100% of my cpu. The macbook is lagging and almost unusable.

Build times:

```
Command line: 
Total time: 1 mins 35.025 secs

Android Studio:
Total time: 4 mins 23.928 secs
```

If instant run is disabled, I get the same times as on the command line.
When profiling the full build I notices that `app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug` takes up to 3 minutes.

Is there a way to improve the performance on a clean build with instant run enabled?

```
Macbook 10.11.5 / Core i7
Android Studio 2.1.1
Gradle tools 2.1.0
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120M
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) SO answer

Comment: I had cold start 1 min in Android Studio. After adding Dagger 2 with "android-apt" it's taking 10 mins on cold start (but still 1 min in command line). Any idea why Instant Run is slow with "android-apt"?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set

> minSdkVersion = 21

in your module's **build.gradle** to get best performance of instant Run.

Source: [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_studio_040716&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#instant-run)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I tried it and the build times are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve your long build times is to turn off Instant Run as follows:

Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and **uncheck Enable Instant Run**.

Comment: Like I stated in my question, I want to improve the cold build time with Instant Run Enabled

Comment: try these suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35446359/923920 . If that doesn't work then report the bug here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210490&thanks=210490&ts=1463708488

Answer (score 0):

You can improve build times by experimenting with [DEX resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#set-up-ir)

```
android {
  ...
  dexOptions {
    maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
  }
}
```

minSdkVersion should 15 or higher to get any profit.

Still you can encounter some [bugs and glitches](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=instant-run&sort=priority&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened).

I had the same issue - cold start for 5-6 min and heating cpu like hell...

With more or less complex project this feature is buggy, so I turned it off.